Models for force in a linearly magnetized medium
Question 0: What is the correct expression for the force on a magnetic dipole: $F=(m \cdot \nabla )B$ or $F=\nabla (m \cdot B)$?
These formulae apply in the case B is the external magnetic field the dipole is subject to, in which case the two are equivalent because the curl of B is zero in a region arbitrarily close to the dipole. Now comes a related problem.
Question 1 (the real question):
Suppose I want to calculate the magnetic force inside a material with linear behviour and coefficent $\mu$. I thought about modelling the material as consisting of many magnetic dipoles with linear magnetization $M=(\mu/\mu_0 -1)H$. Clearly also in this case I get two different expressions depending on how I calculate the force. In case $F=\nabla (m \cdot B)$ the force density f is $f_i=(\mu/\mu_0-1)\partial_i(H_jB_j)$
in the other case $f_i=1/2(\mu/\mu_0-1)\partial_i(H_jB_j)$. In principle I think the argument I used at the beginning to claim that the field was external so the curl of B in the region of the dipole is zero fails because we have that the sources of the field itself are in that region around the ifninitesimal dipole no matter how small we take them. So the answer seems to depend on the model of dipole that we choose (the one whose force is $F=(m \cdot \nabla )B$ is Gilbert's model, the other one is Ampere's I read in some previous discussions). I don't know if this is the best way to see it or if I am missing something else that would allow me to determine a priori the force in the linear medium.
